# Callback on returned promise chain runs before callbacks in the aforementioned promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, babel-polyfill

Context: Codebase I'm working in is a mixture of ES5 and ES6 thanks to babel.

I'm trying to accomplish waiting on a promise (returned by an `async` function in ES6 code) using `.then()` (in ES5 code).

Here's the `async` function I'd like to wait on:

```
static async getSignatureEntities(itemsRequireSignature) {
    const signatureEntities = [];
    if (itemsRequireSignature.length > 0) {
        const chunkSize = 50; //prevent url from getting too long
        const truncatedItemsRequireSignature = //something

        for (const items of truncatedItemsRequireSignature) {
            if (items.length > 0) {
                let page = 1;
                let filter = "sig"
    
                await populateSignatureEntitiesByPageAndFilter(page, filter, signatureEntities);
            }
        }
    }
    return signatureEntities;
}
```

Here's the promise chain I'm returning (in ES5 code) in `getHistoryItems()`

```
return getSignatureEntities(items)
         .then(function(signatureEntities) {
              return setUpFormResponseView() //callback 1
         .then(function(response) {
              return response[0].Data; //callback 2
          });
```

And here's where this returned chain is being waited on

```
return getHistoryItem()
    .then(callback3)
```

What should happen is callback 1 and 2 should run before 3, but what's happening is callback 3 is running before any of them, and the response value passed to callback 3 is a pending promise when it should be a value. It seems like `getHistoryItems` returns a resolved promise before the promise chain is actually resolved.

When stepping through the transpiled code, the `async` function returns at the `await` call and callback 3 starts executing, after which the `async` function resumes, and subsequently callbacks 1 & 2 execute after the function returns (which works as it should).

Comment: We need to be able to see the code that shows the entire call chain you're asking about - all functions in that chain and all the calling code.

Comment: We need to see the code for `populateSignatureEntitiesByPageAndFilter()` and for `setUpFormResponseView()`.  It seems likely that one or both of them is not returning a promise that is properly connected to when they are done.